# installing GTK+3 on CodeBlocks Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, gtk

I am trying to install GTK+3 on windows. It installs but it always tells me that it can't find the file libgtk-3-0.dll. However, GTK+2 works perfectly for me. The main issue is that I am trying to run some interface coded with GTK+3. Only the interface appears but none of the drawing in it! How can I make this work? 
Do I need GTK+3 to make it work? If yes, how can I install it properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed both gtk2 and gtk3 there might be a conflict with you path.
Surely if you installed gtk2 from a setup file (it usually add a path)

I do use both and compile gtk project with codeblock as well.
What I do is a dedicated folder where there is all gtk and dependency dll and always put the gtk executable I've build with CB.
download gtk3 from there http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php and unzip

then create a folder MyGtk for example put all .dll from the /bin directory
copy also the /etc & share content at the root of MyGtk
then copy your .exe app also

everything should run fine.
If not edit your windows path and remove any location to c:\xxx\gtk